# How to use vsim.exe (asim) in Aldec Active-HDL Student Edition?

Tags: vhdl, simulator, active-hdl

I have installed the latest Aldec Active-HDL (Student Edition).

Compiling the source files with `vlib.exe` and `vcom.exe` works like in QuestaSim, but `vsim.exe` behaves different. Moreover, `vsim.exe` has no built-in help `-h` or `--help`.

The testbench is compiled into the VHDL library `test` and the
testbench is named `sortnet_BitonicSort_tb`.

The TCL script contains the run options: `run -all` and `endsim`.
The GUI mode script contains only the `run -all` command.

**My command line:**

```
.\vsim.exe -title sortnet_BitonicSort_tb -do "add wave *; do {D:\git\PoC\sim\aSim.gui.tcl}" -work test sortnet_BitonicSort_tb
```

How can I run my testbench in console mode with TCL script?
And how can I run the testbench in GUI mode with TCL script?

**Edit:**

Executing this command line: `vsim.exe -work test sortnet_BitonicSort_tb` gives an "Access to test denied." popup window, when the GUI launches.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but some notes that may help.

The `vsim` has some help on command line options with `vsim /?`.  Based on this, it looks like you have too many options for GUI run with `vsim`, e.g. `-title` and `-work` does not appear to be supported.  For full documentation, make an account at Aldec, and see Support => Documentation.

For batch run, Aldec points to the `vsimsa` executable, as shown in [Getting Started with Active-HDL Batch Mode](https://www.aldec.com/en/support/resources/documentation/articles/1144).

There is a slightly different command set for `vsim` and `vsimsa`, which is documented in the full manuals available at Aldec after login.

Comment: Damn! As a Windows user, I should have tested `/?` ...There is a `vsimsa.dll`, but no executable (*.exe, *.bat) as noted in the documentation. Maybe it's caused by the Student Edition, which is no full version.

Comment: I have no experience with a Student Edition, but in the ActiveHDL provided with the free [Lattice Diamond](http://www.latticesemi.com/latticediamond) installation there is a `VSimSA.exe`, so consider that.